# Making the 'Series Name' a combination of text and cell data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm having an issue trying to figure out how to create a 'Series Name' for a line chart in Excel to a TEXT + CELL value.

For example, I have two cells labeled 2015 and 2005 in Excel. In my chart, I want the 'Series Name' to be:

2015 + " Test Results"

2005 + " Test Results"
Where 2015 and 2005 are cells L11 and L12 in my sheet.

I have tried the following:

```
=Sheet2!$L$11&" Test Results"

=Sheet2!$L$11" Test Results"
```

I get the error "The formula you typed contains an error."

Not sure what else to try. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I know that this is not an answer to what you are asking, however would typing 2015 Test Results, then formatting "Test Results" to use the same font color as the background, the in cell L11 work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are trying to enter this formula in the actual `Series Name` dialog box for the chart.  This does not work.  Excel expects to see a reference to a single cell or range of cells and not a normal formula.

The normal way to handle this is to set the formula for the 'Series Name' in a cell, and then set the `Series Name` equal to this single cell.

**Formula in `C2`**

```
=E2&" Test Results"
```

**Chart and data series ranges** showing that the `Series Name` is equal to a single cell `C2`.

[image: chart with ranges]

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a very neat trick and I definitly didn't think of that. I did what you described and it worked beautifully!